# Django - passing user related information to many views

Tags: python, django

I would like to view some user information on over half of my website's views.
This information should contain not only trivial username but also some fields from other tables of my project that are associated with current user.
I would also like to put this information into the template that my current view extends, just to keep it DRY.
I already did some research and coded some templatetags hoping that registering tags would help me achieve this but I have no idea how to get user information when there's no request like in views' functions.
Any tips on how to achieve this will be much appreciated. I just started django yesterday and am still a bit confused by it's philosophy.

Comment: Using sessions also requires request data, so... is there any way to get request data other than having it passed like in view functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects) to add data to the template context in a DRY way.

In a nutshell, a context processor is simply a function that accepts a `request` as its first argument, does some additional processing that you add and augments the context with whatever values you want.

You can query an objects models, add the current datetime...pretty much anything you can do with Python or Django can go into a context processor.

Comment: Just one more question, answers from similar topics states that I shouldn't use context processor unless I'm going to use this data on every single view of my website. My website will have other data to display on different subpages in similar fashion to this one. Is it ok in this case to use context processor? Isn't it hindering it's performance?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're going to be doing, it's hard to say whether or not performance would be impacted. You can always put in a conditional check to see if `request.path` matches a certain subset to do certain things on some pages, but not all.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think I will be able to figure out the rest on my own. For now all I'm doing is just firstapp - blog with username shown on every subpage, but in close future I'm going to be working on a big project so I'm already starting to think about performance. Details of it are still unknown to me so I can't precisely ask a question about it.

Comment: You're welcome. Another alternative is just template inheritance. You can always have a template that outputs a value which other templates, but not all can inherit from. Or, you could do a template tag...there are several alternatives.